# Transformation from one basis to another

Tags: geometry, change-of-basis

I have a 3D point $X_1$ in basis $1$. The origin of basis $1$, $O_1$, has a translation of 't' with respect the origin of basis $2$, $O_2$. Also basis $1$ has a relative rotation with basis $2$, given by the rotation matrix $R$.
How do I go about converting $X_1$ from  basis $1$ to  basis $2$ ?

Answer (score 1):

**Rotate, translate**

Call the target vector $Q$. Rotate by the angle $\theta$ in the first coordinate system.
$$
 R Q.
$$

Translate the rotated vector to the second reference frame:
$$
\tilde{Q} = RQ + P.
$$

A pictorial follows. The black vectors mark the first coordinate system. The blue vectors mark a coordinate system which has been rotated by $\theta$, and translated by a vector $P$.

[image: start]

The target vector $Q$ is located in the first coordinate system and the steps to transform to the second coordinate system follow.

[image: data]

First, rotate the vector by the angle $\theta$.

[image: rotate]

Translate the rotated vector by $P$.

[image: final]